# Alternate "Fellowship of the Ring" Opening

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, alternate-version, the-fellowship-of-the-ring

I went to see "Fellowship of the Ring" within its first week of showing at a cinema.

I remember it having a scene at the beginning that has Frodo being asked to tell the story of how he lost his finger.  I have tried to find articles of this scene existing, but have not found any.

I suppose my head may have filled in this scene after I had seen "The Return of the King", but I think not.

Is there any article or other evidence that there was this alternate beginning?

Comment: `Frodo being asked to tell the story of how he lost his finger` I cannot remember Frodo losing his finger in LOTR!

Comment: Doesn't he get it bitten off by Golum?

Comment: @Stefan thanks for reminding me. Looks I like I have to see 'em again!

Comment: Maybe you are remembering [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yW_ocZLaRdI)?

Comment: @Oliver_C I think you may be right.  I was working in a video store at the time.  I'll bet one of the employees played this and my brain combined it with the movie.

Answer (score 15):

There are indications that other prologue narrations were considered, and you might find what you are looking for on the Extended Edition DVD.

From the [DVD Journal review](http://www.dvdjournal.com/reviews/l/lordoftherings_fellows2.shtml) of *The Lord of the Rings: The Fellowship of the Ring:
Extended Edition*

> Under the menu for Visualizing the Story you'll find a featurette
>   called Storyboards and Pre-Viz: Making Words into Images, covering the
>   obsessive planning of every aspect of the film...Also in this section
>   are Early Storyboards, animatics of scenes that were never used,
>   **including an alternate opening with Frodo as narrator**...

And from [imdb](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120737/trivia):

> Originally the narration at the prologue was to be spoken by Elijah
>   Wood, but it was felt that the information imparted had little bearing
>   on the character of Frodo. Ian McKellen also recorded a narration but
>   once again it was felt that Gandalf wasn't the right character to
>   speak it. They eventually settled on Cate Blanchett as Galadriel, as
>   it emphasizes the timelessness of the elves.